# Changing Eclipse Exit Shortcut

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using eclipse on Ubuntu 12.04 and Ctrl+x closes my Eclipse.  I tested Ctrl+x in other applications and it cuts text, which is what I want, so it must be an eclipse shortcut binding.

I checked my Preferences>General>Keys settings and couldn't find an exit/quit/explode eclipse command and when I search for Ctrl+x I only see 'Cut' binded to that key combo.

It has been driving me crazy so any help will be appriciated, you go to cut and omg eclipse is closing lol.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Here's how to solve it:

1. When you open Eclipse, go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys.
2. Search for the 'Cut' command. The Binding option should show 'Ctrl+X'. Change the When option from 'In Dialogs and Windows' to 'Editing Text'.

Comment: A mod should give you more points cause this has been sitting here a very long time! And this is very important to my every day work. No more wasting time waiting for Eclipse to restart.

Comment: For option 2, You can also go to the Exit command and select Unbind Command. I think this is cleaner than changing the behavior of Cut.

Answer (score 0):

I checked my Eclipse environment, I don't have this problem. Ctrl+ X is for cut.

I can suggest to go where you did, and look inside the bindings column, if there is any  ctrl+x and change it.

Look also for other programs you are running, maybe they listen to shortcuts.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I used the search on the Keys preference page and typed "Ctrl+x" it showed Cut = Ctrl+x & To Upper Case=Shift+Ctrl+x.

When I tried ctrl+x in gedit and in chromes search bar it cut text. I'm also using a mac keyboard.

Comment: I feel like this is such a novice question but I just don't know where else to look. It only happens in Eclipse and I checked the bindings...  

I restored default key bindings and now ctrl+x does nothing. This is better than closing eclipse but still not cut err.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem on Windows 8. The CTRL+x binding closed Eclipse but in the bindings dialog the only binding for CTRL+x was for the cut action. Finally, I have found the solution in the Arch Linux Wiki. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/eclipse#Ctrl.2BX_closes_Eclipse . It's a bug in Eclipse which can be solved by editing a metadata file by hand.